# How to know what column has been resized when using TableColumnModelListener

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using **TableColumnModelListener** on a **JTable** to know when a **Column** is resized.

I took a look at the `ChangeEvent` object inside the `columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e)` method, but I didn't found a way to know what column has been resized.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I didn't found a way to know what column has been resized.

In the `columnMarginChanged()` method you can use:

```
TableColumn resizingColumn = table.getTableHeader().getResizingColumn();
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a TableColumnModelListener, you can [add a property listener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#addPropertyChangeListener%28java.beans.PropertyChangeListener%29) to each individual TableColumn whose size interests you:

```
columnModel.getColumn(0).addPropertyChangeListener(
    new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            if (event.getPropertyName().equals("width")) {
                int oldWidth = (Integer) e.getOldValue(); 
                int newWidth = (Integer) e.getNewValue(); 
                // etc.
            }
        }
    });
```